# sigtimedwait and  detecting signals

Tags: c, pthreads, signals

I'm supposed to implement a signal handler which stops all the threads in the program the first time a certain signal is called, and resume them if they are already stopped. I implemented a demon thread running in the background using the following code:

```
void *handle_sig(void *arg)
{
    sigset_t set;
    //set set...

    struct timespec to;
    to.tv_sec = 1;
    to.tv_nsec = 0;

    while (_keepListening) {

        int ret = sigtimedwait(&set, NULL, &to);

        if (ret < 0)
            if (errno == EAGAIN) {
                continue; /* no signal sent*/
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed...\n");
                exit(1);
            }

        if (_state == PAUSE_STATE) { /* was blocked*/
            //do something
        } else {
`                       //do something else
        }

    }
    return NULL;
}
```

The problem is that if a signal is sent and detected, and then another is sent before the while loop is entered again - the second signal is ignored, which can leave the program paused forever. is there a way of detecting if a signal was sent since the last call to sigtimedwait?

Thank you

Comment: Signals are kind of a boolean feature. Either a signal is active or it is not, there is no counter or queue if the same signal happens twice before the first is handled.

Answer (score 0):

You might think about making your processing asynchronous.

For example by starting a thread for "doing something" or "doing something else".